# React/RCTDefines.h file not found in RCTBridgeModule.h

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I was using `Expo` and I separated `expo eject` for module use.

And I tried `pod install` in iOS file. it was work.

> Pod installation complete! There are 51 dependencies from the Pod file
>   and 63 total pods installed.

But An error occurred when the `Xcode` was opened and the `build and run` button was pressed.

[image: error image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testgame",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "jest-expo": "27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^8.1.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "eth-lightwallet": "^3.0.1",
    "ethereumjs-tx": "^1.3.7",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^6.0.0",
    "ethereumjs-wallet-react-native": "^0.6.7",
    "expo": "^30.0.0",
    "expokit": "^1.8.0",
    "formik": "^1.3.2",
    "js-sha3": "^0.8.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.2",
    "node-libs-browser": "2.1.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-fast-crypto": "^1.8.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "git+https://github.com/HCL-HO/react-native-fetch-blob-expo.git",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-pin-view": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-secure-randombytes": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "3.0.4",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.34",
    "yup": "^0.26.6"
  }
}
```

> Xcode Version: 10.2.1

I've never used `Xcode` before, so I'm a beginner. Please explain it in detail. I'd appreciate it if you could explain it with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a `podsec` myself and solved it.

This is not in the official document and requires a fundamental solution from the module developer.

This solution creates a lot of `Warning`. There's nothing wrong with the code.

1. Remove `react-native-secure-randombytes` path from Header Search Path
2. Unlink `react-native-secure-randombytes` module - react-native unlink react-native-secure-randombytes
3. Added react-native-secure-randombytes.podspec from this link
4. Added next code into pod file:

   pod 'react-native-secure-randombytes', :path =>
   '../node_modules/react-native-secure-randombytes'
5. do `pod install'